# UML,difference between "note" and "callout"?

Tags: uml

I'm new by UML,so excuse me if my question is beginner.
In UML diagrams,we can use `callout`s and `note`s.It seems that both of them are used for  annotations(for example showing constraints).

You can see callout there:
1- [Annotate a diagram by using callouts](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Annotate-a-diagram-by-using-callouts-2f3a8780-4bab-45a3-88dc-ad2ac0b79cb9)
2- [Callout shape](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/1283/29/6059_calloutshape.html)
3- [Activity diagram enhancements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27017067)

But what is different between them and also when we have to use each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a **callout** in UML.

Comment: please see my question again.I add more details.If it is not in UML,why it is there?

Comment: There are lots of things in many (UML) modelling tools that are extensions to UML, or just their own specific thing. The IBM link suggests that the callout is part of the SysML language.

Comment: @hasanghaforian see "Figure 7.2 Comment notation" in [www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/). There is **no** occurence of the word _callout_ neither is it part of the UML model same as UML does not contain things like _red line_ or _blue 2pt wide line_. The callout notation is some tool-specific visual enhancement, not forbidden but with no well-defined meaning

Comment: Thanks for the details. @GeerBellekens on one hand you are right : the callout term is tightly coupled with some tools and not very common (visual paradigm, MS office). On the other hand it belongs to a standard. The formal definition of that term is quite a shame. I however think it deserves some interest as it seems to be present in several tools.

Answer (score 2):

To be exhaustive, I consider here the difference between a UML comment and a SysML callout on a conceptual and on a graphical point of view.

**Conceptual difference**

[The Unified Modeling Language User Guide](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/799556306) (Booch et al.) defines in its glossary a UML note as:

> A graphic symbol for rendering constraints or comments attached to an element or a collection of elements

A constraint or comment: in other words, an information that can not be represented by a graphical UML element (or would be painful to represent).

On the other side, a callout is not a coined UML term. It belongs to [SysML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Modeling_Language), which is a UML profile defined in the frame of the OMG. It is difficult to find an explicit definition of that term.

In the [SysML 1.3 formal specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/1.3/) you have in section 16.3.1.1 (p. 144):

> The callout notation can also be used to reflect the relationship of other model elements to a requirement

This is not very explicit. However, in Annex A, p. 168 (which is not, I think, an appropriate place) there is:

> The callout notation provides a mechanism for representing relationships between model elements that appear on different diagram kinds.

`Conceptual synthesis`

On a conceptual point of view, I think this answers your question. The UML note is an element quite flexible to bring indications that are not represented graphically while the SysML callout provides the ability to represent relationships between different diagrams, what should help to build a coherent model.

**Graphical difference**

On a visual point of view, things are quite subtle.

According to [UML Infrastructure Specification, v2.4.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/), section 9.5.1, p. 37, *Comment* - *Notation*:

> A Comment is shown as a rectangle with the upper right corner bent (this is also known as a “note symbol”). The rectangle contains the body of the Comment. The connection to each annotated element is shown by a separate dashed line.

On the other side, in [SysML 1.3 formal specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/1.3/), section 15.3.1.4 on p. 131, *Allocated Property Callout Format*:

> When an «allocate» property compartment is not used, a property callout may be used. An «allocate» property callout uses the same shorthand notation as the «allocate» property compartment. This notation is also shown in Table 15.1. For brevity, the «elementType» portion of the AllocatedFrom or AllocatedTo property may be elided from the diagram.

In table 15.1 (p. 130) there is the graphical representation of an allocation. Each row of the table shows the representation for different node types. It depends on the kind of elements "to" and "from"  subject of the allocation, I guess in the case of the callout the diagram kind and the type and the exact relation between the diagrams.

`Graphical synthesis`

To be synthetic on the graphical side, the graphical notation of a comment is clear, while the graphical notation of the callout depends on the elements on the two sides of the callout (to and from). For more informations, the implementer should report to the 15.1 table defining an allocation representation..

Comment: The linked SysML 1.3 formal specification does not show any examples of using arbitrary weird shape (as shown in the Visio link in OP's question). All examples use the usual rectangle with the upper right corner bent - "note symbol". So what would be the agreed visual difference between _callout_ and _note_?

Comment: Thanks for the note, I was thinking about the conceptual, not visual difference.  It is not an obvious definition at all. I edit my answer.